# What's the correct way to execute this SQL query?

Tags: java, android, sql, cursor

I have two columns `FOO_COLUMN` and `BAR_COLUMN`. I'd like to return all of the results from my database that match `foo` or at least contains `foo` and that also match `bar`. I can run the query without `LIKE ?` and it will return the correct results, my problem is that I just don't understand the `SQL` statement used to also return results that are similar to `foo`.

```
    String selection = FOO_COLUMN + "=? COLLATE NOCASE"
            + " LIKE '?'"
            + " AND " + BAR_COLUMN + "=?";
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {
            foo + "%", bar
    };
    Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(...selection, selectionArgs...);
```

In other words:

I would like to search for **the** and have the query return **The Whatever** from the database as long as the record also matches `bar`. Like, `foo` = **the**, `bar` = **fruit** ---> **The Apple**, **The Orange**

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use a union statement. First find the rows that match arg[0] and then find the rows that are similar to arg[1]. Then you would take the union from both of these statements and get your results.

It would go something like this:

```
SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
String[] subQueries = new String[] {
        "SELECT name_col FROM table1 WHERE " + BAR_COLUMN + "='bar'",
        "SELECT name_col FROM table1 WHERE " + FOO_COLUMN + " LIKE 'foor''"
};
String query = queryBuilder.buildUnionQuery(subQueries, null ,null);
Cursor results = mDatabase.rawQuery(query, null);
```

Comment: @user3949852 I'm not sure I understand your question and by the way it's a whole new question. Although not sure how your provider is configured, you could definitely get it working, by Overriding provider's `query` method.

Comment: This just ends up throwing a `SQLException`.

Comment: @user3949852 the query you used and the full error message would help a lot more.